# Sending SNS push notification message to multiple devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-go

I need to send SNS push notification to multiple devices passing the array of device tokens using `aws-sdk-go` lib.

Currently I'm sending the push message to SNS using this steps:

Creating the endpoint:

```
pl, err := svc.CreatePlatformEndpoint(&sns.CreatePlatformEndpointInput{
    PlatformApplicationArn: aws.String(topic),
    Token: aws.String(n.DeviceToken), // just one device token
})
```

Sending the message to endpoint:

```
params := &sns.PublishInput{
    Message:          aws.String(payload),
    TargetArn:        aws.String(*pl.EndpointArn),
    MessageStructure: aws.String("json"),
}
```

I have not seen a way to send one push message to multiple devices using just one request. Is it possible?

Like this example to illustrate:

```
pl, err := svc.CreatePlatformEndpoint(&sns.CreatePlatformEndpointInput{
    PlatformApplicationArn: aws.String(topic),
    Token: []aws.String{token01, token02, token03}, //array of device tokens
})
```

Comment: This seems more of case for pull rather than push. If at all push, you need to loop and do individual.

Comment: You can subscribe each endpoint to a topic then send the message to the topic, or just do what I do and brute force send one message per device.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: I solved creating a topic, subscribing the devices in this topic and sending the push message to the topic.

Comment: any example , how to subscribing the devices to topic